# BeautifulSoup4 .replace "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" (Beginner)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I get an error that says `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

I believe that variable *sphere* is a string, if printed- outputs a line of information that contains `<a href="http://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://website/image.png/"><i class="icon-camera"></i><strong>find similar</strong></a>`, but `.replace()` gets a `None` value (I think)

If `sphere` is given a value of a string, it works perfectly

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://example.com/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
contents = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')


link = soup.find_all('a')
print (link[34]) # prints a line that I need
sphere = link[34]

sphere.replace('<a href=http://www.google.lt/searchbyimage?image_url=', '') # error here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case although it may appear like `sphere` is a string, if we inspect `type(sphere)` we see it's a `bs4.element.Tag`. The simplest solution is to just cast it as a string first:

```
sphere = str(link[34])
sphere.replace('<a href=http://www.google.lt/searchbyimage?image_url=', '') # error here
```